# LeetCode #1120 Maximum Average Subtree (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

This code snippet shows 2 common patterns I see a lot in Python that I don't really like:

1. Arbitrarily-named, narrowly-scoped recursive function
2. Inappropriate data type (in this case, an array `ans` to store 1 float) used purely for its mutability and scope, to store side-effects from some other scope

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def maximumAverageSubtree(self, root: TreeNode) -> float:
        ans = [0]
        def helper(node):
            if not node:
                return 0, 0
            left_sum, left_count = helper(node.left)
            right_sum, right_count = helper(node.right)
            ans[0] = max(ans[0], (left_sum + right_sum + node.val) / (left_count + right_count + 1))
            return left_sum + right_sum + node.val, left_count + right_count + 1
        helper(root)
        return ans[0]
```

`ans` has to be an array, even though we just want to store one scalar value, because if we tried to use a float it would not be visible inside `helper`. This seems like an ugly shortcut to me.

And the other pattern I don't like is defining `helper` just so we can do recursion with additional return values for logic, then return `helper`'s side effects. Is it normal to define short, sort of "throwaway" functions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Non-Local Variables

`ans` is visible (for reading) inside of `helper`.  It just can't be changed, although its contents can be modified.

So yes,  `ans = [0]` is an ugly hack.  You don't need it.  What you need in its place is `nonlocal`.

```
def maximumAverageSubtree(self, root: TreeNode) -> float:
    ans = 0

    def helper(node):
        nonlocal ans     # <--- Refer to ans in outer (but not global) scope

        if not node:
            return 0, 0

        left_sum, left_count = helper(node.left)
        right_sum, right_count = helper(node.right)

        ans = max(ans, (left_sum + right_sum + node.val) / (left_count + right_count + 1))

        return left_sum + right_sum + node.val, left_count + right_count + 1

    helper(root)

    return ans
```

### Arbitrary-named, narrowly-scoped recursive function

In this case, you're going to need to get used to it.

Instead of creating a new function, which is visible outside the `maximumAverageSubtree` function, this `helper` is only useful to this function.  It does not need to exposed to the outside, so it makes sense to hide it inside.

This is a common paradigm in Python.  Decorators use this all the time.  For example, a `@timed` decorator has an internal `wrapper()` function.

```
def timed(func):

    def wrapper(*argv, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        result = func(*argv, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        print(func.__name__, "took", end_time - start_time, "seconds")
        return result

    return wrapper
```

The function shouldn't be arbitrarily named; its name should reflect its purpose.  Here, we are wrapping a call to another function, so `wrapper()` makes sense.

Above, you have a `helper()` function.  That probably could be named better.  Maybe `process_subtree(node)`.  But it is "scoped" inside `maximumAverageSubtree()`, so its name doesn't need to repeat that level of detail.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `nonlocal`, I like that a lot. Like `global` without all the namespace pollution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a hack or nonlocal variable, return the maximum average:

```
class Solution:
    def maximumAverageSubtree(self, root: TreeNode) -> float:

        def helper(node):
            if not node:
                return 0, 0, 0

            left_max_avg, left_sum, left_count = helper(node.left)
            right_max_avg, right_sum, right_count = helper(node.right)

            this_sum = left_sum + right_sum + node.val
            this_count = left_count + right_count + 1
            this_avg = this_sum / this_count

            this_max_avg = max(left_max_avg, this_max_avg, right_max_avg )

            return this_max_avg, this_sum , this_count

        max_avg, _, _ = helper(root)

        return max_avg
```

Or, in this case you could use a class instance variable:

```
class Solution:
    def maximumAverageSubtree(self, root: TreeNode) -> float:

        def helper(node):
            if not node:
                return 0, 0

            left_sum, left_count = helper(node.left)
            right_sum, right_count = helper(node.right)
            this_sum = left_sum + right_sum + node.val
            this_count = left_count + right_count + 1

            self.ans = max(self.ans, this_sum / this_count)

            return this_sum , this_count

        self.ans = 0
        helper(root)
        return self.ans
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to define an object property outside of `__init__`, or should they always first be declared inside `__init__`?

Comment: Generally, it's good to put it in __init__.  If you expect to call maximumAverageSubtree more than once, self.ans would have to be reinitialized every call.  Using @AJNeufelds's answer with `nonlocal` or returning the max avg as in my first answer is a better approach.

Comment: Should probably be `if not node: return float('-inf'), 0, 0`